# Kendo combo-box with virtualization and setting index

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

Combo box not binding the data with k-index.

I have given the index as 0(zero) because I want to set first item as default.

I have demonstrated the issue in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/aAsjzmtLHeB3agSAWkxI?p=preview).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="KendoDemos">
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                <select kendo-combo-box
                        k-placeholder="'Select product'"
                        k-data-text-field="'ProductName'"
                        k-data-value-field="'ProductID'"
                        k-filter="'contains'"
                        k-ng-model="selectedProduct"
                        k-index="0"
                        k-data-source="productsDataSource"
                        k-cascade="productsOnCascade"
                        k-on-change="productsOnChange(event)"
                        k-virtual="productsVirtualOptions"
                        k-height="200">
                </select>
        </div> 
    </div>
        <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can slim down your html a bit and not include all those options and use k-options instead to specify your data-source, events, and other options. IMO easier to manage.

```
<select kendo-combo-box
    k-filter="'contains'"
    k-ng-model="vm.selectedProduct"
    k-options="vm.productsOptions">
  </select>

  vm.productsOptions = {
    dataSource: productsDataSource,
    virtualOptions: productsVirtualOptions,
    onCascade: productsOnCascade,
    onChange: productsOnChange,
    index: 0,
    height:200,
    dataTextField: "ProductName",
    dataValueField: "ProductID",
  };
```

Your on the right path but your ng-model for the drop down was set to an empty string which doesn't relate to the actual properties you set towards the combo box text/value fields. If you initialize the ng-model to null it sets the correct index you specified it'll work.

Take a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TYuOHX8pxjwzAwUQ1rNx?p=preview) and see if it helps you out at all.

Comment: If we initialize the k-ng-model to some object like below line, also fixing this issue.
{ "ProductID": "5639f5f65c818127b294a518", "index": 0, "ProductName": "CHEAPOUT" }
But after filtering from the text-box item selection is not working.

Steps to reproduce.
1. Type some text(eg: ZILLAN).
2. Open the combo-box.
3. It selects the first item.

Comment: Could you update your plunkr or mine with a textbox having the functionality you described so I can take a look at it for you?

Comment: k-on-change should be changed to k-change or if you use k-options your angular scope variable should have change not onChange. See my attached plunkr and see if it works like expected I'm using k-options. http://plnkr.co/edit/TYuOHX8pxjwzAwUQ1rNx?p=preview

Comment: Ive also forked your plunkr and changed it to work like mine
http://plnkr.co/edit/XpVJA0kzIE1Ipdv6U8qr?p=preview

Your change function call in the k-combo-box was off a bit. You dont have to pass the parameter event like this k-change="productsOnChange(event)". You just need to call k-change="productsOnChange". The change and cascade events are logged in the console since alerts lag plunkr